# Charged 41.184% duty on a microprocessor. Is this the correct rate?

Tags: india, customs

I purchased an Intel processor from eBay US which was sent to India via EMS. It arrived today and I got a hefty bill for INR 5120 which is 41% of the declared value of the item.

These were the papers attached to the parcel:

[image: img]
[image: img]

They show the "Rate of duty" as 41.184%. Is this correct? I thought after GST was implemented electronic components were charged only 18%.

Comment: Sales tax and import duties are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought after GST was implemented electronic components were charged only 18%.

Yes and No. GST does not replace Customs Duty. Customs Duty is additional and separate. Earlier most electronic goods were exempt from customs duty [or were charged at 0% to 5%. Few around 28%]. As part of make in India initiative, the customs duty rates have been revised ... you would need to consult experts.

In this specific case as the item did not quote specific import classification code, the item was charged at maximum of the category. Ideally the customs officer should have classified this as HS Code: 84733010 [meant for micro processors] that is at 0% customs duty. But charged as cable and socket [??] at the rate of around 23% plus

Additionally there is IGST of 18% on these items take the total rate to 41% plus

Comment: That makes sense, the eBay seller never used the word "processor" in the declaration form. Is there any way I could get a refund of the excess duties? The assessment was made at Chennai Air Customs.

Comment: @customduty567 You can write and try. However getting a refund check from customs after shipment has reached you is next to impossible.

Comment: Section 27 of Customs Act, 1962 says refunds are possible if paid in excess and I found that there is a [separate page](http://www.aircustomschennai.gov.in/refund.html) for refunds. Do you feel it is worth trying?

Comment: I just read the text on the 2nd image I posted and it clearly says I shouldn't have accepted the package if I wanted it to be reassessed. So that closes all doors for me :'(